# How to resize the children WebView/JFXPanel from the JPanel without loading URL every time?

Tags: java, swing, webview, resize, jpanel

I have a `JPanel` in a `TabbedPane`, that contains a `JFXPanel` with a `WebView` and I set a `ComponentListener` on the panel, in order to resize its child, the `JFXPanel` with the `WebView`, every time I resize the panel. What I want is that the content from the URL (a website) does not get loaded every time I resize the panel. I want the content to remain loaded and only get resized.

The content that is being loaded, is the homepage of a website and for example when I resize the panel, I am being redirected to that homepage, that I set as URL and I don't want to lose the page, that I currently open.

The second reason for avoiding the reloading is that sometimes it lasts for a few seconds and I would like to avoid this overload.

I tried with a static variable initially in order to open the URL just one time, but when resizing, the page isn't being shown anymore...there appears only a white page.

Here is the code:

```
public class RtcOverview extends JPanel {

String url = "http://10.112.85.142:8080/petshopJSF/";

public RtcOverview() {
    super();
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.doLayout();
    this.add(jfxPanel);
    this.addComponentListener(new java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter() {
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            initComponents();
        }
    });
}

private void initComponents() {
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final WebView view = new WebView();
            int width = getParent().getWidth();
            int height = getParent().getHeight();

            view.setMinSize(width, height);
            view.setPrefSize(width, height);

            engine = view.getEngine();
            engine.load(url);

            Scene scene = new Scene(view);
            jfxPanel.setScene(scene);

            Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: `this.addComponentListener(new java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter() {
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            initComponents();`  The logic in that code is ..a train wreck.  1) The `LayoutManager` should resize child components according to the logic and layout constraints defined when the component was added. 2) Even if the app./panel is resized, it makes no sense to call `initComponents()` (which creates a new `WebView` and loads an URL) a second time!

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I'm a newbie...and I would be very thankful if you could give me an example of how to resize the children, without creating them and loading the url every single time.

Comment: *"..I would be very thankful if you could give me an example"*  As I would be thankful if you actually followed my suggestions...

Comment: *"..actually followed my suggestions.."*  Note that the latest edit is not compilable code (because of the `...` dross), does not have imports and has no `main(String[])` so it is neither an MCVE or an SSCCE.  If you read those links and failed to understand, read them again.  If you have not read them, read them *now.*

Comment: Sorry if the code doesn't rescpect the rules of the MCVE and SSCCE, I will try to follow them next time I post a question. I solved it with your suggestion and I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andrew Thompson gave me this answer in the comment above. There is no need to call the method initComponents() every time the JPanel gets resized. Instead of using this block

```
this.addComponentListener(new java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter() {
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        initComponents();
    }
});
```

I used the following

```
this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

this.add(jfxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

and it worked. The JFXPanel gets resized like its parent JPanel without needing to load the url again and initialize all the variables every single time.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  :)  +1 for reporting back.